# tabindex between 2 form elements ONLY

Tags: html

Is it possible to set tabindex so by pressing TAB i could switch back and forth between just 2  form input fields?
If not, is there any other way that i could switch between these 2 fields with keyboard only?

Comment: Use `shift-tab` combined with `tab`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in HTML, because browsers may, and actually do, have items external to the page content in the tabbing order. Typically, at least the address bar appears there.

It is apparently not possible with JavaScript either, except with a trick: insert a dummy third input field, make it transfer focus to the first field when focused on, and position the dummy field off-screen (with positioning; using `display: none` does not work, since it it is then not focusable). Example:

```css
:focus {
  background: yellow
}


/* just to show where the focus is */
```

```html
<input tabIndex=1 id=first>
<input tabIndex=2>
<input tabIndex=3 onfocus="document.getElementById('first').focus()" style="position: relative; left: -100000px">
```

Comment: FYI: it doesn't considers Shift + tab, perhaps you should like in my answer https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/232794/342

Answer (score 0):

Shift + tab makes you go back to the previous "TAB index" and only TAB makes you go to the next index, i think there isn't a method to "loop" trough 2 index